# Update height constraint programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am new in auto layout. I have done all of my project from xib file, but now I faced a problem where I have to update an view's height programmatically. I have tried below but now working.

```
[[self view] addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:loginContainer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:loginFrame.size.height]];
```

In console it's shows

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78724530 V:[UIView:0x790cdfb0(170)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x787da210 V:[UIView:0x790cdfb0(400)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78724530 V:[UIView:0x790cdfb0(170)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Instead of adding an entirely new constraint, why not just update the existing one? Create an IBOutlet to the existing constraint and alter the `constant` value.

Comment: You should make an IBOutlet to the height constraint you made in IB, and modify its `constant` property in code.

Comment: this `loginContainer` is a subview of a view which is loaded from `[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibName:` how could I create an IBOutlet here?

Comment: @j.f. how to update an existing constraint?? can you show me.

Comment: @TapasPal, the answers already given below are what I was going to suggest.

Comment: Yes I had use it, I just want to avoid the loops, though it's look an inexpensive operation.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Instead of adding a new constraint, you need to modify the constant on your existing constraint.

Use an IBOutlet to connect to your constraint in Interface Builder:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
```

Then, when you need to set it programmatically, simply set the constant property on the constraint:

```
heightConstraint.constant = 100;
```

OR

If you can't access the nib in Interface Builder, find the constraint in code:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in myView.constraints) {
    if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeHeight) {
        heightConstraint = constraint;
        break;
    }
}
heightConstraint.constant = 100;
```

And in Swift:

```
if let constraint = (myView.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == .width}.first) {
            constraint.constant = 100.0
        }
```

Comment: I can't create this because this loginContainer get loaded from a external xib file which is not a member class of self.

Comment: If you don't already have a reference to the constraint you need, looping through all of the view's constraints is the only way to get the reference you need.  But considering you should only ever have a handful of constraints belonging to a particular view, and you're just checking an enum value, this a VERY inexpensive loop.

Comment: Attention. The condition is insufficient, it should be constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeHeight && constraint.secondAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute to exclude getting ratio constraint

Answer (score 23):

To get a reference of your height constraints :
Click + Ctrl in the constraint and drag and drop in your class file :

[image]

To update constraint value :

```
self.heightConstraint.constant = 300;
[self.view updateConstraints];
```

Comment: I can't create this because this loginContainer get loaded from a external xib file which is not a member class of self.

Comment: this xib is not related to any class ?

Comment: yes.. it's a external xib file which get loaded by NSbundle

Answer (score 18):

A more flexible way using this swift extension:

```
extension UIView {    

    func updateConstraint(attribute: NSLayoutAttribute, constant: CGFloat) -> Void {
        if let constraint = (self.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == attribute}.first) {
            constraint.constant = constant
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

How to use this view extension to update constant value of existing constraints:

```
// to update height constant
testView.updateConstraint(attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, constant: 20.0)


// to update width constant
testView.updateConstraint(attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, constant: 20.0)
```

Comment: What is `self.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == attribute}.first`? how do I know if will find the right constraint?

Comment: Note: NSLayoutConstraint.height has been renamed to NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height and NSLayoutConstraint.width has been renamed to NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 4.2**

Using auto layout and animation to increase height of button

I don't use story board. all things in code.

```
import UIKit

class AnimateHeightConstraintViewController: UIViewController {
    var flowHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(button)
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        flowHeightConstraint = button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
        flowHeightConstraint?.isActive = true
    }

    @objc func animateButtonTapped() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.flowHeightConstraint?.constant = 100
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    lazy var button: UIButton = {
       let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(animateButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
}
```

and result is like this:

[image]

Comment: ty, you saved my life!

Comment: If you have more views they all animate

Comment: Thanks! You saved me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 8):

Let's call your view nibView. So, you are trying to load that view in a view controller, so first, in your view controller, you need to load it as you are doing it with:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NibView" owner:self options:nil];
```

Then you need to tell the nibView that you don't need it to transform the autoresizing masks into constraints by doing

```
nibView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

Then, you can add your constraints

```
    NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:nibView
                                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                     toItem:nil
                                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                                   constant:yourValue];
```

And finally just add it to your view constraints:

```
[self.view addConstraint:heightConstraint];
```

You probably would need to add a width constraint also.