# what is square brackets in code for ios apps (xamarin)

Tags: xamarin.ios

I've tried to google this question, but didn't find what i'm looking for.

Im looking for some code examples for xamarin ios and very often meet constructions like this:

```
[cell setIndentationLevel:SOME_NUMBER];
[cell setIndentationWidth:SOME_OTHER_NUMBER];
```

And like this:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
            indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return intOffset;  
}
```

How to use them?
And can they be used in Xamarin studio for ios apps?

Comment: Please link to where you saw those examples for xamarin ios.

Comment: That looks like Objective C. Xamarin studio uses C#, but you can write native bindings in Objective C, but you would first need to learn it. This isn't a very good question as it's not a programming problem, and it's very open. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: to weston: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060373/update-height-constraint-programatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Objective-C and not C#. It is a different programming language. You'll need to "convert" it to C# to be able to use it in your app. (Assuming those are UITableViewCells), the C# equivalent would be:

```cs
cell.IndentationLevel = SOME_NUMBER;
cell.IndentationWidth = SOME_OTHER_NUMBER;
```

You need to do more research/learning into Objective-C, C#, and iOS if you're not able to tell the difference between those two languages and you want to do iOS development.